# Can webpack be configured to provide externals in a non-library project?

Tags: commonjs, webpack

I'm currently using webpack to build a front end application that includes an API and requires a provided SPI (inheriting from a base implementation). I can easily declare the provided SPI as an external with the following config

```
{
    externals : {
        "spi": "commonjs spi" //provided by container
    }
}
```

It would also be quite useful to provided a base SPI implementation, and the apps API as external components (to be used by my front end module loader).

**example input**

```
//spi_base.js
function SpiBase () {}
SpiBase.prototype.doFoo = function () {doBaseImpl();}

//main.js
var foo = require('spi_base');
```

**desired output**

```
//main.js
var foo = __webpack_require(1)__;
define("spi_base", __webpack_require(1)__);
```

I think what I'm looking for is similar to the expose-loader https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader, but exposing it via commonjs syntax instead. Am I understanding this correctly? If so, does a loader like this exist? If not, is there a better way to solve the problem?